# Logging different project libraries, with a single logging library

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a project in Apps script that uses several libraries. The project needed a more complex logger (logging levels, color coding) so I wrote one that outputs to google docs. All is fine and dandy if I immediately print the output to the google doc, when I import the logger in all of the libraries separately. However I noticed that when doing a lot of logging it takes much longer than without. So I am looking for a way to write all of the output in a single go at the end when the main script finishes.

This would require either:

- Being able to define the logging library once (in the main file) and somehow accessing this in the attached libs. I can't seem to find a way to get the main projects closure from within the libraries though.
- Some sort of singleton logger object. Not sure if this is possible from with a library, I have trouble figuring it out either way.
- Extending the built-in Logger to suit my needs, not sure though...

My project looks at follows:

**Main Project**

- Library 1
- Library 2
- Library 3
- Library 4

This is how I use my current logger:

```
var logger = new BetterLogger(/* logging level */);
logger.warn('this is a warning');
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of writing to the file at each logged message (which is the source of your slow down), you could write your log messages to the Logger Library's [ScriptDB](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script-db/) instance and add a `.write()` method to your logger that will output the messages in one go. Your logger constructor can take a `messageGroup` parameter which can serve as a unique identifier for the lines you would like to write. This would also allow you to use different files for logging output.

As you build your messages into proper output to write to the file (don't write each line individually, batch operations are your friend), you might want to remove the message from the ScriptDB. However, it might also be a nice place to pull back old logs.

Your message object might look something like this:

```
{
  message: "My message",
  color: "red",
  messageGroup: "groupName",
  level: 25,
  timeStamp: new Date().getTime(), //ScriptDB won't take date objects natively
  loggingFile: "Document Key"
}
```

The query would look like:

```
var db = ScriptDb.getMyDb();
var results = db.query({messageGroup: "groupName"}).sortBy("timeStamp",db.NUMERIC);
```

Comment: Wow, great answer! I had not thought of ScriptDB at all. Even better I would be able to query my logs. However I don't yet understand the purpose of the messageGroup, could you give an example of the kind of information you would store in there?

Comment: My initial though was that `messageGroup` would ask as a logger-instance variable. It could be used a bunch of ways: You might have it store a unique value for each run and use the same group across all libraries. (Add an `init` type function to your library.) Or there could be one `messageGroup` for each library, then you query by run start (set in the constructor). You might even create a new instance of the logger in each function and achieve great granularity. I was really just suggesting the inclusion of some data beyond the log message it self to make the logger more flexible.

Comment: Note: ScriptDB was deprecated on May 15, 2014